# Accessing multidimensional array data with flat array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

This problem is driving me up a wall and I can't figure out what's going over my head here:

I'm trying to instantiate a 1D array in order to simulate a 3D array.

I'm instantiating my array as:

```
int *cache = new int[width*heigh*depth];
```

and accessing it with

```
int data = cache[x + width * (y + depth * z)];
```

where x is the vertical index, y is the horizontal, and z is the depth.

In my implementation, I need n*4 indices, where n = width*height and 4 is the z value.

I have x and I have width, and from these I can calculate height (it can be assumed that x/width is always a whole number).

The problem I am experiencing is that the aforementioned indexing schema only works when the "width" value is 2!

I need to access elements of my array in separate instances where width can be 1, 2, 4, or x(with height of 1).

I wrote the following code to demonstrate the discrepancies.

numWays is the "width" I want.
numSets is the "height".
blockCount is the total number of blocks and is equivalent to numWays*numSets.

The code prints out an error if the calculated index is larger than the maximum index allowable in my array, which should logically be (blockCount*4)-1.

```
   int cacheSize = 1024;
   int blockSize = 8;
   int blockCount = cacheSize/blockSize;
   int numWays = 2;
   int numSets = blockCount / numWays;

   int maxAllowableIndex = blockCount*4-1;

   for(int set = 0; set < numSets; set++){
      for(int way = 0; way < numWays; way++){
         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            if(set+numSets*(way+4*i) > maxAllowableIndex) std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
         }
      }
   }
```

Errors are printed for any run where numWays != 2, even though numWays*numSets = blockCount. Why is this, and how can I modify my indexing schema to do what I want?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following 2 lines:

> `int data = cache[x + width * (y + depth * z)];`
>
> where x is the vertical index, y is the horizontal, and z is the depth.

I think you have not been careful enough. You should do something like:

```
int data = cache[z + depth * (y + width * x)];
```

Indeed, if you think in decimal system, you do
unit + 10*tens + 100*hundreds. But what you are doing is hundreds + 10*tens + 100*unit.

Hope it helps !

Tony

Answer (score 2):

I would say the 3D access should be:

```
int data = cache[(width * height * z) + (width*y) + x];
```

- One plane of the cuboid has size width*height, Multiplied by z it gives you your "depth" within the cuboid.
- One plane has width "width". Multiplied by y it gives you the line of the plane.
- And x is just x.

Ok brackets are unnecessary...